# Possible ranges of variables that are defined by inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, inequalities

There are the following inequalities `0.09 <=(a1*a2)/(a1 + a2) <= 0.2` and `1 >= a1/a2 >= 0.5`

How can all possible values of the variables `a1` and `a2` satisfying these inequalities be found?

I would like the answer to be in the form of inequalities (something like that `...<=a1<=...` and `...<=a2<=...`).

Comment: `Reduce[Rationalize[
  0.09 <= (a1 a2)/(a1 + a2) <= 0.2 && 1 >= a1/a2 >= 0.5], {a1, a2}]`

Comment: @Artes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending @Artes a little bit:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[Reduce[Rationalize[(.09 <= (a1*a2)/(a1 + a2) <= .2) && (1 >=a1/a2 >= .5)], {a1, a2}], {a1, a2}];

RegionPlot[\[ScriptCapitalR], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the details!